# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Container while trying to install Visual Paradigm

Tags: java, awt, noclassdeffounderror, ubuntu-14.04, visual-paradigm

I'm trying to run Visual Paradigm Community Edition installer and I am getting this error in terminal - GUI installer never shows up (Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, Oracle Java 8):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Container
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.ConsoleScreenExecutor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.InstallerConsoleScreenExecutor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.getScreenExecutor(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
Could not display the GUI. This application needs access to an X Server.
```

`java -version returns:

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Is this a problem with my JRE? I have installed Visual Paradigm before on Java 7 and didn't have this issue.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm facing the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Missing 32 bit libraries are causing the problem I think. This helped in my case:

```
sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libxtst6:i386

sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386

sudo apt-get install libx11-dev:i386

sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
sudo apt-get install libxi6 libxtst6 libxrender1
```